# UINavigationController, how to hide tabbar in second level viewController then show tabbar in third level viewController

Tags: ios

here is a piece of my code, but in this way, when I push the third level view controller, the tabbar won't show.

```
//at first level
SecondLevelViewController *_2vc = [[SecondLevelViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondLevelViewController" bundle:nil];
    _2vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_2vc animated:YES];  

//at second level
ThirdLevelViewController *_3vc = [[ThirdLevelViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdLevelViewController" bundle:nil];
    _3vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_3vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the values of hidesBottomBarWhenPushed when you initialise the view controllers, you should instead handle the hiding mechanism in the -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated in the view controllers instead.

An example of this implementation would be:

In SecondLevelViewController.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [_bottomBar setHidden:YES];
}
```

In ThirdLevelViewController.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [_bottomBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: It works. But I wonder why setting hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property to NO won't work when pushing the third level view controller?

Comment: I'm assuming hidesBottomBarWhenPushed is a BOOL variable no? If it's just a bool variable, you can't expect it to hide/display views by itself. You will need to implement the hide/display code somewhere in your view controller. In this example, I set the hide/display code in the viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 2):

```
    // Load the view
    AddViewController *aController = [[AddViewController alloc] init];

    // Set the view title
    aController.title = @"Add View";

    // hide tabbar
    aController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

    // add it to stack.
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:aController animated:YES];

 -(void)viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated
 {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
 }

-(void)viewWillDisappear: (BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: I am assuming the first bit of code should be encapsulated in the `viewDidLoad` method? Also, can you add a bit of explanation as to what is happening here?